# Wrong text is being extracted using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text using beautifulsoup but whenever I define the div and class then I am getting the wrong text.

I need to extract from this [page](https://www.frag-team-clean.de/de/startseite/waschen/wie-entfernst-du-schweissflecken.html) and I want to get only this part
[image]

This is my code and I don't know what's wrong I am doing.

```
request = Request("https://www.frag-team-clean.de/de/startseite/waschen/wie-entfernst-du-schweissflecken.html")
soup.find('div', {'class':'text section'}).get_text()
```

Comment: This class will be used for many parts of the page. Try using the full selector. Right click the page, inspect, find the element in the element inspector, right click it and select copy selector (in Chrome style browser). Should give you something like this: `body > main > div > div.root.responsivegrid > div > div.parsys.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--12 > div.layoutpanel.layoutpanel__style--lateralGreyPadding > div > div > div:nth-child(3)`. Here is where you get the selector: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyFAM.png).

Comment: Also try parsing the <p> and <ol> tags inside it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import requests
import bs4

req = requests.get("https://www.frag-team-clean.de/de/startseite/waschen/wie-entfernst-du-schweissflecken.html")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
print(soup.find("div", {"class": "title__base atomic-width-control--component"}).text.strip() \
 + soup.find("div", {"class": "text section"}).text.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.frag-team-clean.de/de/startseite/waschen/wie-entfernst-du-schweissflecken.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
title = soup.find("div", class_="title title__style--salmon section").get_text(strip=True)
text_section = soup.find("div", class_="text section")
para = text_section.find("p").get_text()
lis = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in text_section.find_all('li')]

print(title)
print("---" * 10)
print(para)
print("---" * 10)
print("\n".join(lis))
```

Output:

```
Was sind die einzelnen Schritte, um Schweißflecken zu entfernen?
------------------------------
Wenn du die folgenden Schritte beachtest, kriegst du Schweißflecken gut raus:
------------------------------
Stelle sicher, dass das Oberteil waschbar ist.
Wähle Waschmittel wie zum BeispielSpee Color GeloderPersil Universal Kraft-Gelund Fleckentferner.
Reibe das Waschmittel auf den Fleck oder lasse das Oberteil bei hartnäckigen Flecken einweichen.
Wasche es bei der höchstmöglichen Temperatur.
Prüfe, ob der Fleck weg ist. Falls nicht, wiederhole die Schritte.
```